# How To Remove A List Of Classes At Window Width - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me optimize this Jquery to remove a list of classes from the DOM? The code that I have works, but there must be a way to do this without having to list each class individually.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   if(window.innerWidth <= 960) {
      $('.wow').removeClass("wow");
      $('.animated').removeClass("animated");
      $('.bounceInDown').removeClass( 'bounceInDown' );
      $('.slideInLeft').removeClass( 'slideInLeft' );
      $('.slideInRight').removeClass( 'slideInRight' );
      $('.zoomInUp').removeClass( 'zoomInUp' );
   }
});
```

Comment: Nope, not really, you can do `$('.wow, .animated, .etc').removeClass('wow animated etc')` but that may or may not do what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could list all classes into a single selector and remove all classes at once, like `$('.animated,.bounceInDown,.slideInLeft,.slideInRight,.zoomInUp').removeClass('animated,bounceInDown,slideInLeft,slideInRight,zoomInUp');`, but this will remove all of listed classes for each of the selected elements, which might not be what you want to accomplish.

You could use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like:

```
["animated", "bounceInDown", "slideInLeft", "slideInRight", "zoomInUp"].forEach(function (e) {
  $('.' + e).removeClass(e);
});
```

Comment: Of course. .forEach is the solution for this.I was overthinking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try extending jQuery:

```
$.fn.classGoByeBye = function(){
    var selector = this.selector.replace('.', '');
    $(this).each(function(){
        this.classList.remove(selector);
    });
};

//usage:
$('.wow').classGoByeBye();
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to place your list of classes in an array and then iterate over them within your condition. For example...

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
    $.each(['wow', 'animated'], function(index, value) {
        $("." + value).removeClass("." + value);
    });
}
```